# How can I configure the jasmine's random on gruntfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I configure the random option using grunt-contrib-jasmine? I can do it directly with jasmine's command line, but running jasmine's task by grunt-cli I didn't find the random option. Then the output of command line always shows the specs' randomic output.

Example updated:

Below the Jasmine's json:

```
{
  // Spec directory path relative to the current working dir when jasmine is executed.
  "spec_dir": "spec",

  // Array of filepaths (and globs) relative to spec_dir to include and exclude
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],

  // Array of filepaths (and globs) relative to spec_dir to include before jasmine specs
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],

  // Stop execution of a spec after the first expectation failure in it
  stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: false,

  // This is the random option I need on gruntfile
  random: false
}
```

Below the gruntfile json:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
         pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
        ,jasmine : {
             myapp  : {
                 src   : ['src/**/*.js']
                ,options : {
                     specs : 'spec/**/*{s,S}pec.js'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    ...
```

Comment: if you can add some command example that would be helpful

Comment: I did update the description, @intika.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. At least I've tested and it worked.
On the each describe declaration's top, you can configure the random option of your Suit Test. It can be with the following statement:

```
describe('My suite', function(){
   jasmine.getEnv().configure({random:false});

   // There are several tests here... 

   afterAll(function(){
      jasmine.getEnv().configure({random:true});
   });

   ...
```